# Opening an xlsx file in Windows 7 opens Excel 365 but without the document loaded

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, file-association, office365

I see that there are similar questions posted, but none of the solutions work or they are for different versions of Excel & Windows. Let me try a question specific to my situation.

The problem (annoyance): when I double-click an `.xslx` file, select from recent documents, etc, Excel is launched. However, it launches without the file being opened. There is no error message shown. The file opens fine if I open it *from Excel*; I just cannot launch Excel *with the file loaded*. I am using Windows 7 & Office 365.

What I've tried:

- Disabling Options -> Advanced -> General -> Ignore other applications that use DDE. Just for fun, I even tried with this enabled and after re-disabling it.
- Unassociating `.xslx` with Excel and re-associating
- Running a repair on Excel
- Having the version updated (this is a corporate install where fixes are pushed to me)
- Checking the Windows application logs in event viewer; no errors appear when attempting to launch the file.
- When I run excel directly from the command line with the document specified, i.e. `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\Path\to\my\file.xlsx"`, it launches as expected. This makes me think the problem lies with my Windows configuration, not Excel.
- `assoc .xlsx` shows `.xlsx=Excel.Sheet.12`
- `ftype Excel.Sheet.12` shows `Excel.Sheet.12="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" /dde`
- Others that have *working* file launch have the same `assoc` and `ftype` settings.
- The "edit" context menu command in Explorer has the same problem as "open"

What I cannot try:

- Changing the specific details of file association; File types in Folder Options in Explorer do not exist in Windows 7, so I cannot change the command line parameters. I have, however, checked file associations the Windows 7 way.

Any idea what would cause Windows to not launch Excel as expected when opening a file?

**More clues**:

Looking at the process that was launched, the document path is entirely missing from the command line; this is all that was run:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" /dde

Somehow the file isn't being added to the command line.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: To be clear, the only reason I mentioned "corporate" was because I wanted to avoid "check for updates" advice. I'm still admin on the computer.

Comment: "File types in Folder Options in Explorer do not exist in Windows 7" -> replaced with Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Set Associations. Take a look there for any oddities.

Comment: Everything looks fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. The strange thing to me is that it works *without this change* for others, so more answers would be appreciated if someone knows more about the inner workings of the shell. By entering this in an elevated command prompt (adding a `%1`):

> ftype Excel.Sheet.12="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" /dde "%1"

...the file path now gets passed to Excel, and launching a file now works.

Comment: FWIW, the default setting does *not* include `"%1"`.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add another solution to the *exact* same symptoms (able to open with command prompt, and by browsing within excel, but not from file explorer) can be explained by the missing DDEExec registry keys.

Example:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Addin\shell\Open\ddeexec
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\ddeexec
```

These keys will be missing for every parent key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel*\
```

My workaround involved exported each key on a working computer (with the same excel versions) and importing them on the problem system. At the time I didn't think to use PowerShell so you only get 1/2 of the solution automated. This one-liner will import all the `.reg` keys in the folder you specify.

```
gci "PATH TO FOLDER CONTAINING .REG FILES" |select -expandp fullname|%{&([scriptblock]::create("regedit /s $_"))}
```